# How to pass '#' in query string

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, query-string

I want to pass '#' to the query string like `?page.aspx?someParam=1234#5`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please use `Server.UrlEncode` on your querystring that will parse the '#' for you

Comment: Actually, I think you want to URLEncode, not HtmlEncode.  There's a difference.

Comment: I think you might mean UrlEncode... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx

Comment: this is a bloody great answer hats-off to hatsoft!

Comment: One thing I found out that you dont have to use Server.UrlDecode just use Request.QueryString["someParam"]

Answer (score 10):

Try using `%23`. This is the url encoded value for `#`.

Answer (score 4):

URL-encode the sharp character: `%23`.

Answer (score 0):

try using escape(url parameter value) method in url instead of only parameter value

Answer (score 0):

The best way to pass `#`, `&` and other **special characters** without causing problems in asp.net query string is to use `Server.UrlEncode()`

See the following example.

```
  private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
     Response.Redirect("page.Aspx?"+"someParam="+Server.UrlEncode("1234#5")); 
  }
```

or use `%23` replacing `#` but I think the more suitable way is using `Server.UrlEncode()` so you can use other special characters without any problem.