# Parsing and encoding URL before sending to Rest webservice

Tags: java, rest, url-encoding

I am developing an App where I am sending get request to REST web service using 
`@RequestMapping(value = "myURLpattern", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "image/png")`

I came across a bug if somebody enters # in the URL query String it breaks from there
`http://myserver.com:8080/csg?x=1&y=2#4&z=32&p=1`

So I tried to encode it via filter `HTTPRequestWrapper` so that `#` will be replaced by `%23` using `URLEncoder`.

My problem is for encoding URL, first I need to read the `URL(request.getRequestURL())`.
and getURL again can't read string after #.
`request.getRequestURL()` will return only `(http://myserver.com:8080/csg?x=1&y=2)`

Is there any other way to parse the complete url and encode it before sending to REST web service?

Answer (score 3):

That is not a bug. Check this:

[What is the meaning of # in URL and how can i use that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192742/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-url-and-how-can-i-use-that)

A # in the url query string is wrong. You should encode it on client side, before sending it to your server. See this one: [How to pass '#' in query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297504/how-to-pass-in-query-string)
It is in asp, but you should find the java equivalent.

Something to get you started can be this one [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding)

Comment: Thanks for your reference so if some one enters # in one of Html field like serial number:12#ser4 then we can not parse it on server side.
http://myserver.com:8080/csg?serial=12#ser4&manufacture=12-07-2013&warranty=3

for the above scenario how we are going to handle it

Comment: Encode it on the client side. Take a look at encodeURIComponent function in javascriopt. encodeURIComponent('12#ser4'); would make '12#ser4' become '12%23ser4' which is what you should be sending to the server, so your request would look like that: http://myserver.com:8080/csg?serial=12%23ser4&manufacture=12-07-2013&warranty=3